# How to call a child method from filter_var callback in parent

Tags: php, filter-var

I have a child class that holds a bunch of private properties.  The parent class has the `__SET` & `__GET` methods.

The parent `__SET` method has `filter_var($var, FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'childMethod');` but it always fails with the error `filter_var(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback`

See example code below, you can copy and paste it into http://phpfiddle.org/lite/

For "childMethod" I have tried using:

- `$this->childMethod()`
- `$this->childMethod`
- `this->childMethod`
- `this->childMethod()`
- `childMethod()`
- `childMethod`

all error

```
<?php
abstract class a {
    public function callChild() {
        $var = $this->iAmChild();
        echo $var."<br />";
        echo filter_var($var, FILTER_CALLBACK, ["options" => 'this->callback'])."<br />";
        echo $this->callback($var)."<br />";
    }

    // abstract function callback();
}

class b extends a {
    public function iAmChild() {
        return "I am the child function";
    }
    public function callback($value) {
        $value = strtoupper($value);
        return $value;
    }
}

$child = new b();

$child->callChild();




function convertSpace($string)
  {
  return str_replace(" ", "_", $string);
  }

$string = "Peter is a great guy!";

echo filter_var($string, FILTER_CALLBACK,["options"=>"convertSpace"]);
?>
```

Is it possible?

Each child class is a representation of a database table, so I want to filter and control the "setting" of the properties.  Each child class has the list of properties, and an array or arrays that provide the type of `FILTER_*` to use for each property.  this works for all of them except the `FILTER_CALLBACK`.

How can I pass the child method as a callback function to `filter_var`?

Comment: i don't remember the details, but i'm pretty sure the solution is `['options' => [$this,'childMethod']]`

Comment: ...as for details see docs on [callable type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: thank you @hanshenrik that is what was missing.

Comment: Thank you @skyboyer, The docs are not very clear with use of filters and callbacks.  I didn't even know that callable type page existed.

Comment: @Chad, yes, php.net works really like a charm when you know what to search for. as a guide it is not the best thing.

Comment: @skyboyer shure is!  I just didn't know to search for 'php callable', thanks again for sharing.  The funny thing is that I was using the correct structure in `call_user_func` I just didn't make the connection, nore do the docs on the filter pages give that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as noted in the comments was to change the 6th line of code from
`echo filter_var($var, FILTER_CALLBACK, ["options" => 'this->callback'])."<br />";`
to
`echo filter_var($var, FILTER_CALLBACK, ["options" => [$this, 'callback'])."<br />";`